# PHP Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Gestor_Documental\\Modelo\\Usuario.php on line 22,

Tags: mysql, php7, apache, xampp

Este es el código de Usuario.php  donde me indica el error en la lineá 22 `if ($datos['nombre_usuario'] != "" || $datos['nombre_usuario'] == $nombre_usuario)`

```
   <?php
require_once "Conexion.php";
class Usuario extends Conectar{
    public function AgregarUsuario($datos) {
        $Conexion = Conectar::Conexion();
        if (self::BuscarUsuarioRepetido($datos['nombre_usuario'])) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (nombre,nombre_usuario,email,contrasena) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $query = $Conexion->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('ssss',$datos['nombre'],$datos['nombre_usuario'],$datos['email'],$datos['contrasena']);
            $exito = $query->execute();
            $query->close();
            return $exito;
        }   
    }  
    public function BuscarUsuarioRepetido($nombre_usuario) {
        $Conexion = Conectar::Conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT nombre_usuario FROM usuario WHERE nombre_usuario = '$nombre_usuario'";
        $result = mysqli_query($Conexion, $sql);
        $datos = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if ($datos['nombre_usuario'] != "" || $datos['nombre_usuario'] == $nombre_usuario) {
            return 1;
            } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

El código de Registro de Usuario es

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Registro de Usuario</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Vista/Imagenes/Astroproyect3.png" type="image/png">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vista/css/Mis_Estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="nav">
            <a class="boton" href="Index.php">Pagina de Inicio</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="div">
            <header>Registro de Usuario</header>
            <form id="Registro" class="form" method="POST" onsubmit="return AgregarUsuarioNuevo()">
                <p>
                    <input placeholder="Nombre Personal" required="required" class="entrada" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" required="required" class="entrada" type="text" name="nombre usuario" id="nombreusuario" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input placeholder="Correo" required="required" class="entrada" type="email" name="email" id="email" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input pattern="[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*" title="La contraseña debe empezar con una letra y contener al menos un dígito" placeholder="Contraseña" required="required" class="entrada" type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input class="miboton" type="submit" value="Registrarse" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="Libreria/Bootstrap4/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Libreria/Bootstrap4/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function AgregarUsuarioNuevo() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    data: $('#Registro').serialize(),
                    url: "Controlador/Usuario/Registro/AgregarUsuario.php",
                    success:function(respuesta) {
                        alert(respuesta);
                        respuesta = respuesta.trim();
                        if (respuesta == 1) {
                            $("#Registro")[0].reset();
                            swal(":D","Agregado con Exito","success");
                        } else if(respuesta == 2) {
                            swal("Este usuario ya existe, por favor ingrese otro!!!");
                        } else {
                            swal(":(","Fallo al Agregar","Error");
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Al ingresar los datos en el formulario estos suben normalmente a la base de datos pero el sweet alert muestra Fallo al agregar y no limpia el formulario; Localhost muestra `PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Gestor_Documental\\Modelo\\Usuario.php on line 22, referer: http://localhost/Gestor_Documental/Registro%20de%20Usuario.php`

Comment: Antes de ese if donde te da el error comprueba que `$datos != null` porque tiene pinta de que no te está obteniendo nada.

Comment: La función BuscarUsuarioRepetido la ejecuta con éxito pero la funcion AgregarUsuario retorna Fallo al agregar.

Comment: Lo que te quiero decir es que con el mismo código ejecuta una función con éxito pero al ejecutarlo con la otra función arroja error.

Comment: y cual es el ouput de $dato? usa un var_dump o esta libreria: https://github.com/IcarosNetSA/BOH-Basic-Output-Handler

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debes revisar si $datos es null cuando llega a la línea 22.

Quiza así:

```
if ($datos && $datos['nombre_usuario'] == $nombre_usuario)
```

Comment: Cuando llega a la linea 22 con la función `BuscarUsuarioRepetido` la ejecuta con éxito , pero al ejecutarla con la función `AgregarUsuario` esta me arroja el error.

Comment: Adicional al realizar el `DEBUG` con Netbeans este muestra que ` $exito = $query->execute();` retorna 1 lo cual no entiendo porque el servidor arroja esta falla.

Comment: En este caso lo que entiendo es que 1 es la respuesta a la consulta de  `AgregarUsuario`

Answer (score 0):

Tu función `BuscarUsuarioRepetido` tiene varios problemas:

El primero es que estás pasando a buscar valores en `$datos` sin asegurarte siquiera si esa consulta arrojó datos. En los casos en que el usuario no exista, tendrás el problema que estás teniendo ahora mismo. O, si hay fallos en la consulta, tendrás el mismo problema. La mejor forma para comprobar si un  usuario existe es contando los registros que cumplan el criterio. Además, esta comprobación no tiene sentido: `if ($datos['nombre_usuario'] != "" || $datos['nombre_usuario'] == $nombre_usuario) {`. Con el `$datos['nombre_usuario'] != ""` estás diciendo que si EXISTE un usuario con datos en blanco, haga como que no EXISTE. El usuario existe, sólo que tiene sus datos en blanco. ¿Qué sentido tendría esto realmente?

Luego, la consulta es vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. ¿Por qué si en `AgregarUsuario` usaste consulta preparadas, en `BuscarUsuarioRepetido` no las usas? Sé coherente en tu código.

Finalmente, hablando siempre de la coherencia. Esta función debería devolver un `true` o un `false`, no un `1` o un `0`. Pero no nos vamos a meter en este asunto. Lo menciono para que lo tengas en cuenta y adaptes tu código. La diferencia puede ser fundamental en ciertos contexto, como una respuesta que será consumida en otro sitio, o integrada a un modelo de datos donde se requiriese una respuesta del tipo booleano (verdadero o falso).

Aplicando las correcciones, tu código podría quedar así:

```
public function BuscarUsuarioRepetido($nombre_usuario) {
    # Variable para vincular el total de filas encontradas
    $total=0;
    $Conexion = Conectar::Conexion();
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM usuario WHERE nombre_usuario = ?";
    $query = $Conexion->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param('s',$nombre_usuario);
    if( $query->execute() ) {
        $query->bind_result($total);
        $query->fetch();
    }
    # Usamos un ternario para retornar 1 si hay datos
    # o retornar 0 si no hay datos. 
    # Convendría poner simplemente return $total > 0;
    # en cuyo caso se retornaría el booleano de esa comprobación
    return $total > 0 ? 1 : 0;     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que tienes mal tu sentencia sql y por eso te retorna un array vacio, ya que no hace la instruccion. Deberias checkar esta imagen, es lo mismo pero funcional y en ingles.[image: Imagen del codigo donde hace exactamente lo que deseas]

Comment: El código debería ir como texto por favor

Comment: En preferencia el código formateado como texto. Al menos explicar un poco la solución que has redireccionado. O porqué está mal la sentencia SQL no solo decir que está mal sin explicar algo.

Comment: No tenía el código a mi disposición, así tome captura a un video donde subí el funcionamiento del sitio web. Mañana subo el esa sección del código.